# How to setup the first admin user in Jenkins as part of the initial install and not through the UI?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-api

I am planning to launch Jenkins in a Docker container and would like to set up the admin user as part of the initial install and not via the UI.

Answer (score 0):

You can find it here

```
docker exec <container_name> cat /var/jenkins_home/secrets/initialAdminPassword
```

But I do not think there's a way to manually set it during installation.

Comment: No I am using it on Mesos and dont see the inital admin password, I want to configure my docker image so that when it spins up it comes with a user and a password. I know there is a folder /var/jenkins_home/users/ that has the users in it